# Spring Integration Custom Poller for Different Events

Tags: java, spring, directory, spring-integration, poller

I need to poll a folder for changes i.e. files added, modified and deleted.

If I want to distinguish between the different types of events listed above would I need to implement a custom poller i.e. implement AbstractPoller. I have already implemented a poller that does this for a different project but would like to us spring integration and batch as I need to use other functionality.

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you mind to share your code? BTW you always can utilize the custom code with `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>` as a `ref` and `method`, where an underlying POJO will return some object which will become as `payload` of message.

As you know the `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>` should be configured with `<poller>` how often you want to call that undelying POJO.